# C++ Sort enemies by life

Tags: c++, sorting, game-engine

I have a problem with my little game which I have programmed, with the help of a c++ book.

So first I have a class called PlayerObject, and a array with all game objects stored in.
When the game starts, I loop through all the objects inside the array.

```
while (true) {
  for (auto i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    auto object = FuncObjectId(i);

    if (PlayerObject.IsEnemy(object) &&
        PlayerObject.Player.Position.Distance(object.Position) < 1000) {
      // enemies found in range
      FuncMoveTo(object)
    }
  }
}
```

But what if there are several enemies in the given range? How can i order them ?

sorting by life or distance, for example.
So that my player move to the closest target, or to the lowest health target.

Besides, the whole thing has to reset somehow.
The player should not stop after killing the target,
he should automatically go to the next enemy with the lowest life/closest position.

Comment: Yomight look at `std::sort` ?

Comment: And potentially `std::copy_if`

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat. For example, you could copy all 'interesting' object_ids into a temporary container and sort it by objects' health. You will have to do sort for each iteration of the main loop, so it's not too effective. One more way to do it will be to use more effective data structure to store objects, indexed by distance and/or health.

Answer (score 1):

First of all change for loop to

```
for (auto i = 0; i < FuncObjectId.size(); i++)
```

Why only look for 100 enemies?

If player should move all the time just not look for the enemies that are closer then 1000 but You have to sort them by distance to player.
To do this You should use std::sort
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/
You can use this function to sort enemies by parameter You want.

Answer (score 1):

For your given problem, I'd assume that you have a comparatively short list of enemies, below a thousand for instance. If that is the case, you don't really need real sorting, simply search the smallest entry:

```
minimal health found = health of first enemy
corresponding index of enemy = index of first enemy
for all enemies:
    if health enemy < minimal health found:
        minimal health found = health enemy
        corresponding index of enemy = index enemy
```

If, however, for some reasons you still need to actually sort them, the simplest way is to store them in a sortable container (you can write one, but simply go with `std::vector` or `std::list`). Define a method within the enemy class that defines a "smaller than" relationship (`bool health_lower(const PlayerObject& a, const PlayerObject& b)`) and then use `std::sort` with that method as comparator.

Another way is that you write a class that stores the list of enemies, and every time that either an enemy is created or the health of one changes, the class bubbles that particular enemy, as the order of the other enemies to each other does not change.